How to respect different crawl-delays while looping through url array?
In urllib3 or requests modules and while using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures, how can I respect different crawl-delays while looping through an array of urls?
In the example below, the first three urls belong to the same server and share the same crawl-delay (So, after scraping one page, I may not make another request so the same or another page on the same server before the delay period has passed).
The other urls are on different servers and need to respect another or no crawl-delay.
urls = [
    "https://news.ycombinator.com/",      #Crawl-Delay 30
    "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=2",  #Crawl-Delay 30
    "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=3",  #Crawl-Delay 30
    "https://www.infoworld.com/",         #Crawl-Delay None
    "https://www.theregister.com",        #Crawl-Delay 5
]

Here is an extract from the code I am using:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.content
    return BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(fetch_url, url): url for url in urls}

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            url = futures[future]
            try:
                soup = future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing {url}: {e}")


use dict like urls = [{'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/", 'DELAY': 30}, {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/", 'DELAY': 30}, {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=2", 'DELAY': 30}, {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=3", 'DELAY': 30}, {'URL': "https://news.infoworld.com/", 'DELAY': 0}, {'URL': "https://news.theregister.com/", 'DELAY': 5},]

@SergeyK Thanks a lot for the answer! How would I integrate that in the concurrency setup above? I am not clear how to tell the scraping logic to pause for a certain time for one server while scraping may continue with other host servers at the same time.

This code basically uses a queue to have threads take their own specific url, then sleep for the 'DELAY' and perform some logic.  this should work, but you must edit this code to contain your desired logic and scraping.  Good Luck!
import threading
import queue
import time
import requests

q = queue.Queue()
urls = [{'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/", 'DELAY': 30},
        {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/", 'DELAY': 30},
        {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=2", 'DELAY': 30},
        {'URL': "https://news.ycombinator.com/?p=3", 'DELAY': 30},
        {'URL': "https://news.infoworld.com/", 'DELAY': 0},
        {'URL': "https://news.theregister.com/", 'DELAY': 5},]


def scrape_sites():
    global q
    while not q.empty():
        url_data = q.get()
        url = url_data['URL']
        delay = url_data['DELAY']
        while True: # replace this with some logic that will stop the loop when you want
            try:
                res = requests.get(url)
                # do your bs4 scraping stuff here
                time.sleep(delay)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            

for _ in range(q.qsize()):
    t = threading.Thread(target=scrape_sites).start()


Thank you so much for the code! My understanding is that in this example, there are multiple threads getting started almost at the same time. So, even if there is a sleep delay getting applied in each thread, the sleep time would end at almost the same time in each of the threads. After that, several threads could still be sending requests to the same host in parallel and thus ignore the required crawl-delay. Maybe I am missing something here?
I am really struggling to use concurrency while properly respecting different crawl-delays.

I ended up storing the time each host was last contacted. I am storing in a global variable. If the time passed since the last contact, is less than the required crawl-delay, the thread is sent to sleep until crawl-delay requirement is met.
To be thread-safe, this logic is happening in a locked space in each thread, as described here: https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe/#How_to_Make_Critical_Sections_Thread-Safe
